# Any one help me to remove google map top black bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have embedded a google map to my site but it show me a top black bar with my name I want to remove them. you can see the image what I am asking
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9R4q.png)

I tried to remove them using JavaScript but mu JavaScript can't able to append style in hed part of this map can any one help me in this

Here is my javascript code

```
var cssLink ="<style>.QUIbkc{display:none;}</style>";
$('head', window.frames['newiframe'].document).append(cssLink);
$('#newiframe').contents().find("head")[0].appendChild(cssLink);
```

Here is My iframe code

```
<iframe id="newiframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1HtXJoNB0yb5t8HRnt5spDguSxknoV-I&amp;hl=en&amp;ehbc=2E312F" width="100%" height="250" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">

</iframe>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Comment: @MohitSharma Can you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

could find anything related to it on the docs but you could try doing this

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
iframe {
    border: 0;
    margin-top: -75px;
    height: 400px;
}
.RemoveTop {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="RemoveTop">
<iframe id="newiframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1HtXJoNB0yb5t8HRnt5spDguSxknoV-I&amp;hl=en&amp;ehbc=2E312F" width="100%" height="250" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: it's work but I need a solution in js

Comment: you can wrap the iframe in a div and do
div.style.overflow = 'hidden'
div.style.position = 'relative'
div.style.top = 'X px'
same goes to the iframe you can just give it styles from js

Comment: var div = document.getElementById('RemoveTop')
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
div.style.overflow = 'hidden'
div.style.position = 'relative'
div.style.top = '50px'
iframe.style.border = '0'
iframe.style.marginTop = '-75px'
iframe.style.height = '400px'
just like this

Answer (score 0):

In your map embed code, add this at the end of the url:
&hl=en&ehbc=FFFFFF

So your map url looks like this:
https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1ePTPA8tSsomecodeornameofthemapgoeshereGCP9_xGy_6A&hl=en&ehbc=FFFFFF

And the top bar will be #FFFFFF. It's not ideal but at least the name and icons are not visible.

Another solution is to add both position:absolute and top="-60px" to css.